# How to use parse_exprs with ellipsis(dots)

Tags: r, rlang

passing multiple arguments not working
    Tried with  3dots ... and !!! 3 bangs. but error.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang) 
tf1= data.frame(y=c('price'), grp= c('stock'),x=c('time') 
,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    > 
dat= data.frame(price=c(20,12,24,34,12,34,56,88),               
stock=c('fb','fb','fb','fb','ms','ms','ms','ms'),time=c(2,4,6,8,2,4,6,8))
my_fun2 <- function(.x, .num_var, ...){
   group_var <- parse_exprs(...)
   print (group_var)
   num_var <- parse_expr(.num_var)

   x %>%
    group_by(!!!group_var) %>%
     mutate(avg = mean(!!num_var), n = n(), 
            sd = sd(!!num_var), se = sd/sqrt(n)) %>%
     distinct(!!!group_var, .keep_all = TRUE)  }
 my_fun2(dat, tf1$y, tf1$grp,tf1$x)
```

> Error in parse_exprs(...) : unused argument (tf1$x)

As below

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(rlang)


 tf1= data.frame(y=c('price'), grp= c('stock'),x=c('time') ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 dat= data.frame(price=c(20,12,24,34,12,34,56,88), 
                 stock=c('fb','fb','fb','fb','ms','ms','ms','ms'),time=c(2,4,6,8,2,4,6,8))
 my_fun2 <- function(.x, .num_var, ...){
   group_var <- parse_exprs(...)
   print (group_var)
   num_var <- parse_expr(.num_var)

   x %>%
     group_by(!!!group_var) %>%
     mutate(avg = mean(!!num_var), n = n(), 
            sd = sd(!!num_var), se = sd/sqrt(n)) %>%
     distinct(!!!group_var, .keep_all = TRUE)

 }

 my_fun2(dat, tf1$y, tf1$grp,tf1$x)
```

Actual out is summary statistics by group.

> Error in parse_exprs(...) : unused argument (tf1$x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the values passed are string, we can do this more easily with `group_by_at`.  Also, make sure the strings convert to symbol (`sym`) and evaluated (`!!`) in `mean`, `sd`

```
my_fun2 <- function(.x, num_var, ...){
      group_var <-  c(...)        

       .x %>%
         group_by_at(vars(group_var)) %>%

         mutate(avg = mean(!! rlang::sym(num_var)), n = n(), 
                     sd = sd(!! rlang::sym(num_var)), se = sd/sqrt(n)) %>%
                      distinct_at(vars(group_var), .keep_all = TRUE)
         }
my_fun2(dat, tf1$y, tf1$grp, tf1$x)
# A tibble: 8 x 7
# Groups:   stock, time [8]
#  price stock  time   avg     n    sd    se
#  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    20 fb        2    20     1    NA    NA
#2    12 fb        4    12     1    NA    NA
#3    24 fb        6    24     1    NA    NA
#4    34 fb        8    34     1    NA    NA
#5    12 ms        2    12     1    NA    NA
#6    34 ms        4    34     1    NA    NA
#7    56 ms        6    56     1    NA    NA
#8    88 ms        8    88     1    NA    NA
```

The `sd` and `se` are `NA` as there is only one observation per group

Comment: No error. But same code is  printing first 3 columns only. Is this full code?. I understood your point on 'NA'.

Comment: @kamal Yes, it is the full code.  Have you loadded `plyr` also with `dplyr`.  In that case, you may need to explicitly specify `dplyr::mutate`

Comment: @kamal Also, I used `dplyr_‘0.8.3’`

Comment: had loaded tidyverse

Comment: @kamal Can you try on a fresh session with only `dplyr` loaded

Comment: still same result

Comment: Note that my dplyr version is `0.8.3` and `rlang` `0.4.0`

Comment: dplyr  8.0.1, rlang 0.4.0

Comment: @kamal Okay, that could be the issue because `group_by_at/distinct_at` is recent.  Pleaes update your `dplyr`

Comment: namespace automaticall adding plyr

Comment: installing Dplyr 0.8.3 and removal of plyr worked. Thank you very much for such a quick response. Appreciate.  I checked it already.

Comment: i did by green tick. is that the one?

Comment: can you see it?

Comment: where. i do it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197904/discussion-between-kamal-and-akrun).